# WPF Combox.FindName() doesn't work

Tags: wpf, combobox, findname

I've got two comboboxes. The items of the first one i'm filling in Xaml with:

```
<ComboBox Name="ddl_pageType" Width="200" BorderThickness="5">
                <ComboBoxItem Name="Website" Content="Webseite"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Name="CNIProg" Content="Seite"/>
</ComboBox>
```

and the function ddl_pageType.FindName("Website"); works.

The second combobox i'm filling with:

```
 ddl_cniProg.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding());
 ddl_cniProg.ItemsSource = progList;
```

where proglist is List. Here the function ddl_cniProg.FindName(string) doesn't work.

What do i have to do to get an item from dd_cniprog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FrameworkElement.FindName` searches for child elements via the `Name` attribute. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx) Unless  the ComboBoxItems you are generating from the databound list have the Name attribute set (which it doesn't look like from the small code snippet) then the function won't find them.

To find the element you're looking for using `FindName`, you'll need to set the `Name` attribute for each item, either via databinding or programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't specify any name for the items in the databound `ComboBox`, you can't use `FindName`...

If you want to retrieve the `ComboBoxItem` for a specific data item, you can use the `ItemContainerGenerator` :

```
ComboBoxItem comboItem = ddl_cniProg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as ComboBoxItem;
```